# Как получить значение поля элемента xml файла?

Tags: java, xml, исключения

есть XML файл:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<studentsList>
    <student>
        <code>0</code>
        <lastName>bessonov</lastName>
        <firstName>leonid</firstName>
        <patronymic>valentinovich</patronymic>
        <phone>89061234567</phone>
    </student>
    <student>
        <code>1</code>
        <lastName>petrov</lastName>
        <firstName>leonid</firstName>
        <patronymic>valentinovich</patronymic>
        <phone>89000000000</phone>
    </student>
</studentsList>
```

Необходимо провести сравнение фамилии из $lastName с полями lastName в файле.

```
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("student");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    if(node.getChildNodes().item(1).getNodeValue().equals($lastName) == true){
    }
```

Такой if выдаёт мне NullPointerException. Гугл пока ничем не помог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getNodeValue()` возвращает значение узла. Понятие "значение" определено только для некоторых типов узлов, например, атрибутов. Элемент не имеет значения. Он имеет текстовое содержание, которое можно получить при помощи метода `getTextContent()`. В итоге код получится такой

```
if(node.getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent().equals($lastName)){
```